# Code Signing --> Publisher: Unknown - Have correct Chain

Tags: authenticode, ca, signtool

Solved!

Hope you guys can help!

First off. I have gone through every article I could find at SO, as well as MSDN, etc.

I am trying to sign an installshield exe.

I have a godaddy code signing certificate, and have no problem signing the certificate at all. What I do have an issue with is no matter what I do, I get Publisher Unknown on every other computer.

See output below.

**Bottom line: I get no issues signing the cert, but cannot remove the unknown publisher error during the UAC Prompt (The test computers have internet access)**

Also: If I omit the /kp option on verify I get: SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

Final update: 
If I run verify /pa /v temp\setup.exe I get success on the verify, but still an error on the Unknown publish.  The /kp option was used incorrectly on this sign.

Steps:
%SIGNTOOL% sign /v /ac %BUILDROOT%%CERTPATH%%MSCERT% /f %BUILDROOT%%CERTPATH%%CERT% /p %CERTPW% /n "%COMPANY%" /t %TIMESTAMP% %BUILDROOT%%TEMPPATH%\setup.exe

Output:
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: %COMPANY NAME%
    Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    Expires:   Sat Jun 22 14:07:27 2013
    SHA1 hash: 612A38DDED199101442B09D884ED718BBE00D252

Cross certificate chain (using machine store):
    Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Sat Nov 01 09:54:03 2025
    SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

```
    Issued to: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Thu Apr 15 16:07:40 2021
    SHA1 hash: 842C5CB34B73BBC5ED8564BDEDA786967D7B42EF

        Issued to: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
        Issued by: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
        Expires:   Sat May 03 03:00:00 2031
        SHA1 hash: 27AC9369FAF25207BB2627CEFACCBE4EF9C319B8

            Issued to: %COMPANY NAME%
            Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
            Expires:   Sat Jun 22 14:07:27 2013
            SHA1 hash: 612A38DDED199101442B09D884ED718BBE00D252
```

Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed and timestamped: c:\build\temp\setup.exe

Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0

Verify:

Verifying: c:\build\temp\setup.exe
Hash of file (sha1): 62F814EFC81400AD938AB9D9D49B36F7175A098A

Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
    Issued by: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
    Expires:   Thu Dec 31 19:59:59 2037
    SHA1 hash: 47BEABC922EAE80E78783462A79F45C254FDE68B

```
    Issued to: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    Issued by: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
    Expires:   Sat May 03 03:00:00 2031
    SHA1 hash: 27AC9369FAF25207BB2627CEFACCBE4EF9C319B8

        Issued to: %COMPANY NAME%
        Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
        Expires:   Sat Jun 22 14:07:27 2013
        SHA1 hash: 612A38DDED199101442B09D884ED718BBE00D252
```

The signature is timestamped: Sun Jun 24 09:57:57 2012
Timestamp Verified by:
    Issued to: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Expires:   Thu Dec 31 19:59:59 2020
    SHA1 hash: BE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656

```
    Issued to: VeriSign Time Stamping Services CA
    Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Expires:   Tue Dec 03 19:59:59 2013
    SHA1 hash: F46AC0C6EFBB8C6A14F55F09E2D37DF4C0DE012D

        Issued to: Symantec Time Stamping Services Signer - G3
        Issued by: VeriSign Time Stamping Services CA
        Expires:   Mon Dec 31 19:59:59 2012
        SHA1 hash: 8FD99D63FB3AFBD534A4F6E31DACD27F59504021
```

Cross Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Sat Nov 01 09:54:03 2025
    SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

```
    Issued to: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Thu Apr 15 16:07:40 2021
    SHA1 hash: 842C5CB34B73BBC5ED8564BDEDA786967D7B42EF

        Issued to: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
        Issued by: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
        Expires:   Sat May 03 03:00:00 2031
        SHA1 hash: 27AC9369FAF25207BB2627CEFACCBE4EF9C319B8

            Issued to: %COMPANY NAME%
            Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
            Expires:   Sat Jun 22 14:07:27 2013
            SHA1 hash: 612A38DDED199101442B09D884ED718BBE00D252
```

Successfully verified: c:\build\temp\setup.exe

Number of files successfully Verified: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0

Solved!

The issue was the MSI inside the exe installer.  The setup.exe file was signed, but when the msi inside was extracted and ran, that file was not signed.  Signed both, and the error went away!!!